# Install XDebug On OSX

Tags: macos, installation, php

Trying to install `xdebug` on osx, but I get an error `error: make failed` when I run the command `pecl install xdebug`

What do I need to change so I can succesfully install `xdebug` on osx?

```
running: make
Makefile:230: warning: overriding commands for target `test'
Makefile:134: warning: ignoring old commands for target `test'
/bin/sh /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootAeyjJe/xdebug-3.0.1/libtool --mode=compile cc   -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/install/xdebug -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootAeyjJe/xdebug-3.0.1/include -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootAeyjJe/xdebug-3.0.1/main -I/private/tmp/pear/install/xdebug -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/private/tmp/pear/install/xdebug/src -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootAeyjJe/xdebug-3.0.1/src  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /private/tmp/pear/install/xdebug/xdebug.c -o xdebug.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/install/xdebug -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootAeyjJe/xdebug-3.0.1/include -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootAeyjJe/xdebug-3.0.1/main -I/private/tmp/pear/install/xdebug -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/private/tmp/pear/install/xdebug/src -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootAeyjJe/xdebug-3.0.1/src -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /private/tmp/pear/install/xdebug/xdebug.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/xdebug.o
/private/tmp/pear/install/xdebug/xdebug.c:25:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include "php.h"
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [xdebug.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Comment: Do you have the Xcode command line tools installed? `xcode-select --install` or you can just open up Xcode and it should prompt you to install command line tools. If you go the terminal route, I would still open Xcode afterwards to make sure all terms and conditions are accepted. If this doesn't work, let us know which version of the OS you are running.

Comment: Here are two other posts I found that seem to describe your exact issue [Post 1](https://bbqsoftwares.com/blog/xdebug-catalina-issue), [Post 2](https://profilingviewer.com/installing-xdebug-on-catalina.html)

Comment: @DrZoo - I ran the command ``sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`` then  ``sudo xcode-select --install`` and after that, I tried to run ``pecl install xdebug`` and still received the same error